# How to add a door to a wall in UE5?

Tags: unreal-engine5

All the tutorials I find are for UE4 using the supposedly deprecated BSP system.

I have a box mesh shaped like a wall, a door frame downloaded from Quixel, how can I add the door to the wall so that:

1. it cuts the wall
2. disables collision in the door area?

So far I was able to do that using the "Modeling" mode, but it only allows to cut holes using pre-defined shapes, so my understanding is I would need to first create a copy of my asset, then cut the hole, manually create a collision volume so the hole can be walked through, then add the door mesh to cover the hole. Is this really the simplest way to add a door?

In comparison, with BSP I could create a box, add another box and set it to be subtractive, and I quickly made a hole in a wall with proper collision volumes and ability to resize any of the two volumes at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to leave a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that =/

There's no true answer to your question, as it becomes a matter of what you're most comfortable with.

Unreal Engine is slowly moving to become the center of all your DCC needs — control Rig on the animation side, static mesh editing and mesh creation tools for modeling, geometry script for procedural work, etc.

The ideal solution is BSP because you can edit the mesh in the simplest way possible inside the Engine (because the mesh was already most likely simple). [Epic deprecated that in UE5 and replaced it with the Mesh Editor Tools.](https://unrealcommunity.wiki/revisions/616489e95229ed20458b09fe)

There are some tools that Epic is building towards building this; here are some features:

- https://portal.productboard.com/epicgames/1-unreal-engine-public-roadmap/c/262-mesh-editing-toolset-enhancements-experimental
- https://portal.productboard.com/epicgames/1-unreal-engine-public-roadmap/c/490-mesh-modeling-tools-beta
- https://portal.productboard.com/epicgames/1-unreal-engine-public-roadmap/c/259-extended-mesh-creation-tools-experimental

And some documentation on how to edit meshes that already exists: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/WorkingWithContent/Types/StaticMeshes/HowTo/ModifyStaticMeshGeometry/

You can also use Geometry Script for this, but I don't think you'll find an easy solution now. You can change the collision shapes directly in your static mesh editor and change the model directly there, but depending on the complexity of the model, you'll regret it. Unreal Engine is still not a replacement for other DCC tools, even though Epic is moving in that direction.

I would use Blender/Maya/3DMax and make modular parts of the wall, with some parts with holes for doors. Or find a modular pack at sale in the Epic marketplace, for example, https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/medieval-village-mega-pack

I have not checked all features in UE 5.2, so there might be something that helps you more.

EDIT: I had no idea the current tools were so good, here are some videos you should check:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQjZMQXsQLQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TABymp8AzMY

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so it looks like BSP is still a viable solution although deprecated?

Comment: That is correct - I still use it (5.1) to do quick stuff in UE. Here's a video explaining how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ou1V3yh56GA

Comment: Btw, don't let that stop you from checking the new tools: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQjZMQXsQLQ

Comment: A more realistic example here from Quixel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TABymp8AzMY

Comment: @FezVrasta Remember to accept Robo's answer since it appears to be the definitive one.  If someone else comes along with newer information in the future, you can always change the accepted answer then.